# Erro com trigger e excessão

Tags: pl-sql

O detalhe é que estou tentando inserir um cargo e disparar um trigger para guardar a mensagem de acordo ao cargo ser ou não inserido.

O erro é que não consigo capturar a excessão. Quando vou inserir registro que já exista uma pk, o oracle dá o erro relacionado a integridade da pk, mas não salva na tabela de mensagens.

Quando não existe o id, salva normalmente e salva a mensagem correspondente.

```
set serveroutput on  

create or replace trigger tg_mensagem  
after insert  
on cargos  
for each row  

begin  
insert into mensagens values ('cargo inserido');  

exception when  
others then  
insert into mensagens values ('cargo nao inserido');  
end;  
/  

create or replace procedure insert_cargo(v_id_cargo cargos.id_cargo%type, v_cargo cargos.cargo%type, v_salario_minimo cargos.salario_minimo%type, v_salario_maximo cargos.salario_maximo%type)  
as  

begin  
insert into cargos  
values (v_id_cargo, v_cargo, v_salario_minimo, v_salario_maximo);  

commit;  
end;  
/  

begin  
insert_cargo('GF', 'Gerente financeiro', 400, 500);  
end;  
/
```

Como faço para salvad salvar a mensagem mesmo quando houver o erro de inserrsão por causa da chave primária?

Answer (score 1):

Coloca um exception na sua procedure para poder capturar o erro de PK, exemplo:

```
create or replace procedure insert_cargo(v_id_cargo cargos.id_cargo%type, v_cargo cargos.cargo%type, v_salario_minimo cargos.salario_minimo%type, v_salario_maximo cargos.salario_maximo%type)  
as
begin 
  begin 
    insert into cargos  
    values (v_id_cargo, v_cargo, v_salario_minimo, v_salario_maximo);  
  exception 
    when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
      insert into mensagens values ('cargo nao inserido - PK/Unique violados');
    when OTHERS then
      insert into mensagens values ('cargo nao inserido - Erro desconhecido');      
  end;  
  commit;  
end;
```

Não vai ser possível analisar erros como PK na trigger, porque ela só é chamada depois do Oracle validar o insert e os indices (a não ser claro que você insira dados em outra tabela na trigger). Na sua trigger after insert então, basta ter apenas o insert da mensagem de cargo inserido.